# Connect Django to SQL database in Google Cloud's Compute Engine

Tags: django, google-compute-engine

My Django app has been working successfully using Google's App Engine standard environment. However I need to use Compute Engine for more power. I am testing a single VM instance running the app, however it has issues connecting to the POSTGRES database.

The compute engine service account has all the same permissions as the app engine service account.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': '/cloudsql/myproject:us-central1:mypostgresname',
        'NAME': 'mydatabasename',
        'USER': 'myusername',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had success changing the "HOST" field to the public IP address instead of that /cloudsql directory.